# Losing formatting and whitespaces when copying contents across multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was recently using Mozilla's pdf.js library and viewer (as used in firefox) to render pdfs online, and when I view my clipboard, somehow the pdf text copied from the viewer has no line ending. And if I copy them to a text editor, say Atom, all contents becomes one single line.

Essentially when pdf.js renders a document, the text content of a pdf document is wrapped in a layer of div elements with absolute positioning, placed above the underlying canvas image. My questions are:

1. Since divs are block elements, shouldn't I get at least a few line breaks if I copy some contents across multiple divs (or not)? Why copying something from a normal webpage would preserve the formatting?
2. Copying to TextEdit or Microsoft Word wouldn't exhibit the same problem. But why editors like Atom would?

Comment: Regarding question 2, different text editors use different characters for line breaks. Some settle for char(13) while others require char(13) + char(10).

Comment: @Culme Yeah I thought about that, but I tested on Mac, and Atom recognizes both CRLF and LF. I tried to CRLF mode but to no avail...